# How to get count of invocations of my particular Firebase or Google Cloud function from console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console, google-cloud-console

Is it possible to get some overview (in Google Cloud console or Firebase console) where I could see how many times was my Firebase (or Google Cloud) function run? In GC console I can only find graph with "invocations per second" for each of my function. On the other side, in Firebase console, I can only find graph with count of invocations for all my functions together. I would like to know which of my functions consumes my quota. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the count of invocations of each function has been currently added to the Firebase console. The number is available on the main page of "Functions" tab and shows the number of requests for each function per last 24 hours.